# GitHub Licenses API returns a limited set

Tags: github-api

The GitHub API for licenses currently returns only 12 results:

```
$ curl -iG https://api.github.com/licenses
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: GitHub.com
Date: Tue, 05 Jun 2018 04:56:50 GMT
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 2325
Status: 200 OK
X-RateLimit-Limit: 60
X-RateLimit-Remaining: 54
X-RateLimit-Reset: 1528176682
Cache-Control: public, max-age=60, s-maxage=60
Vary: Accept
ETag: "732c80ab130b5c627593816bfe032ba3"
X-GitHub-Media-Type: github.v3; format=json
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: ETag, Link, Retry-After, X-GitHub-OTP, X-RateLimit-Limit, X-RateLimit-Remaining, X-RateLimit-Reset, X-OAuth-Scopes, X-Accepted-OAuth-Scopes, X-Poll-Interval
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains; preload
X-Frame-Options: deny
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Referrer-Policy: origin-when-cross-origin, strict-origin-when-cross-origin
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'none'
X-Runtime-rack: 0.018674
X-GitHub-Request-Id: 8CD8:1459:19390F:3A5318:5B161811

[
  {
    "key": "gpl-3.0",
    "name": "GNU General Public License v3.0",
    "spdx_id": "GPL-3.0",
    "url": "https://api.github.com/licenses/gpl-3.0",
    "node_id": "MDc6TGljZW5zZTk="
  },
  {
    "key": "gpl-2.0",
    "name": "GNU General Public License v2.0",
    "spdx_id": "GPL-2.0",
    "url": "https://api.github.com/licenses/gpl-2.0",
    "node_id": "MDc6TGljZW5zZTg="
  },
  {
    "key": "bsd-2-clause",
    "name": "BSD 2-Clause \"Simplified\" License",
    "spdx_id": "BSD-2-Clause",
    "url": "https://api.github.com/licenses/bsd-2-clause",
    "node_id": "MDc6TGljZW5zZTQ="
  },
  {
    "key": "epl-2.0",
    "name": "Eclipse Public License 2.0",
    "spdx_id": "EPL-2.0",
    "url": "https://api.github.com/licenses/epl-2.0",
    "node_id": "MDc6TGljZW5zZTMy"
  },
  {
    "key": "apache-2.0",
    "name": "Apache License 2.0",
    "spdx_id": "Apache-2.0",
    "url": "https://api.github.com/licenses/apache-2.0",
    "node_id": "MDc6TGljZW5zZTI="
  },
  {
    "key": "lgpl-3.0",
    "name": "GNU Lesser General Public License v3.0",
    "spdx_id": "LGPL-3.0",
    "url": "https://api.github.com/licenses/lgpl-3.0",
    "node_id": "MDc6TGljZW5zZTEy"
  },
  {
    "key": "bsd-3-clause",
    "name": "BSD 3-Clause \"New\" or \"Revised\" License",
    "spdx_id": "BSD-3-Clause",
    "url": "https://api.github.com/licenses/bsd-3-clause",
    "node_id": "MDc6TGljZW5zZTU="
  },
  {
    "key": "lgpl-2.1",
    "name": "GNU Lesser General Public License v2.1",
    "spdx_id": "LGPL-2.1",
    "url": "https://api.github.com/licenses/lgpl-2.1",
    "node_id": "MDc6TGljZW5zZTEx"
  },
  {
    "key": "agpl-3.0",
    "name": "GNU Affero General Public License v3.0",
    "spdx_id": "AGPL-3.0",
    "url": "https://api.github.com/licenses/agpl-3.0",
    "node_id": "MDc6TGljZW5zZTE="
  },
  {
    "key": "unlicense",
    "name": "The Unlicense",
    "spdx_id": "Unlicense",
    "url": "https://api.github.com/licenses/unlicense",
    "node_id": "MDc6TGljZW5zZTE1"
  },
  {
    "key": "mit",
    "name": "MIT License",
    "spdx_id": "MIT",
    "url": "https://api.github.com/licenses/mit",
    "node_id": "MDc6TGljZW5zZTEz"
  },
  {
    "key": "mpl-2.0",
    "name": "Mozilla Public License 2.0",
    "spdx_id": "MPL-2.0",
    "url": "https://api.github.com/licenses/mpl-2.0",
    "node_id": "MDc6TGljZW5zZTE0"
  }
]
```

There are no links to the next page in the headers. So this seems to be the entire result set for the licenses API. Is this expected? I want to find a way to get all license information from GitHub. The only other way I see is to **get** each repository.

Comment: Is there a license that you're expecting to see in the list but is missing? There seems to be 12 options when you choose a license for a new project.

Comment: @JJJ it appears they thought this would show all the licenses on github, regardless of support by their tooling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [GitHub API v3 pagination](https://developer.github.com/v3/?#pagination) states:

> Requests that return multiple items will be paginated to **30 items by default**.
>   You can specify further pages with the `?page` parameter. For some resources, you can also set a custom page size up to 100 with the `?per_page` parameter

So yes, [12 licenses](https://developer.github.com/v3/licenses/) seems to be the full list.

This is consistent with what you see when you [create a new GitHub repository](https://github.com/new), [as commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50692381/github-licenses-api-returns-a-limited-set/50692466?noredirect=1#comment88394542_50692466) by [Ryan The Leach](https://stackoverflow.com/users/306036/ryan-the-leach)

[image: 12 licenses]

Comment: @RyanTheLeach Thank you. I have referenced/illustrated your comment in the answer for more visibility.